Azure API Management (APIM), when using the "Internal" mode restricts access to external APIs call
In Azure API Management (APIM), when using the "Internal" mode, which restricts access to APIs only within the virtual network, automatic download or upload of files through APIs directly using URLs is not supported.
Note : Clients outside the VNet cannot directly call APIs published through APIM in internal mode.
Please advise on the best solution for enabling automatic file downloads or uploads through APIs in an internal mode scenario
MS told APIM is configured in internal mode, it means that APIs published through APIM are only accessible from resources within the same VNet...so looking for alternative solution

I'm confused, what is your question? It sounds like you want to allow external access to APIs in your API Management set to 'Internal' mode?

aims to secure APIM behind an application gateway while enabling access to an internal API. However, APIM cannot automatically import files from an API configured with an internal subnet. APIM's automation capabilities are presently limited to externally accessible APIs.

Have you considered creating Azure Logic Apps or Azure Functions within the same VNet as APIM to handle file operations? Expose these Logic Apps or Functions as APIs through APIM. External clients can then invoke these APIs to trigger file uploads or downloads, and the Logic Apps or Functions can interact with storage services or other resources within the VNet to perform the file operations.
